# ActiveX Component can't create object for Outlook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2003

I am trying to send an email via Outlook.

```vb
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2013
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

At the line: `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`, it gives an error:

> runtime error '429': ActiveX Component can't create object.

I ran this line in cmd:

```
regsvr32 /i "c:\windows\system32\outlvba.dll".
```

It gives me this error:

> The module "c:\windows\system32\outlvba.dll" failed to load.
> Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check
> for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files. The specified
> module could not be found.

Comment: can  you access VBE in Outlook?

Comment: @Omar I can access VBE in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Click2Run edition of Office installed on the problematic PC?

The Click2Run edition of Office 2010 doesn't support automation. See [Office 2010 Click-to-Run compatibility with add-ins](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982431) for more information. Also you may find the [How to: Verify Whether Outlook Is a Click-to-Run Application on a Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864733.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

See [You receive run-time error 429 when you automate Office applications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828550) for more information.

Comment: mine is excel 2003. so what will be the solution?

Comment: See the last link in the post.

Answer (score 0):

i was running into this issue and many many answers pulled me in wrong directions but the final thing that solved this for me was a profile rebuild as somewhere along the way the profile iw as using lost its access to things on the system, dont know how but a rebuild fixed it all for me.