# VBA : ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: vba7

I installed Outlook ( Version see pic) from Microsoft Store.
I want to access Outlook fromp VBA, but It gives me an error (See pic): ActiveX component can't create object (This line : Set objOL = CreateObject("outlook.Application")).
I didn't find Reference Micosoft Outlook 16 object in VBA so I tried late binding:

```
 Dim objOL As Object
 Set objOL = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
```

If you have any idea, Please help me.
Thank you so much,
Rachid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9ZWT.jpg)

Comment: It is missing in the Add References dialog.  So getting "can't create object" is the expected outcome.  Without any info about the install state in the question, recommendation is to spin the repair/re-install wheel of fortune.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
If you do late binding, you don't need to add reference in VBA.
The installation of Outlook is good.

Comment: No, when Outlook is properly installed then it always creates a reference you can see in this dialog.  So it isn't properly installed.  Just like the error message says.  Ask IT staff to help you out.

Comment: Hi Mr Hans, Thank you so much for your time.
You are right, I installed Outlook but it didn't create a reference in VBA references dialog box, an error happened somewhere.
I read in MS Learn article that if you do late binding, you don't need the reference "MS Outlook 16 object library.
........  Here's the article ..................
This is early binding:
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
......................................................
I work from home as Freelance in VBA, No IT staff :-)
Have a great day.

Comment: See [ActiveX Component can't create object for Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30841320/activex-component-cant-create-object-for-outlook-vba).